# How to delete multiple single character from a sentence using R, stringr, etc?

Tags: r, replace, character, stringr

Let's say a string is:

```
aa <- 'am f hate f e w a s b c student'
```

I want to delete all the single character without changing any words. So I hope the result is:

```
'am hate student'
```

I tried stringr:

```
> str_replace_all(aa,'(\\s)[:alpha:]{1}(\\s)',' ')
[1] "af sf e a b scsdv"
```

This is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for a word boundary, a non-space character and a word boundary (and following space).  Remove each such occurrence.

```
gsub("\\b\\S\\b *", "", aa)
## [1] "am hate student"
```